# MSSQL DateTime2 Fail to Update

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, datetime2

Im running stored procedure which in charges to insert, update and delete table's entries.
While both insert and delete runs smoothly, the update operation updates all columns except `DATETIME2` one.

The scenario - I test my Repository pattern (using C# code) in the following way:

1. delete the entire `[BackgroundTaskAttachtment]` table
2. Create 4 new entries
3. delete single entry created on step 2
4. Wait for 5 seconds
5. modify one of the entries

the result is having 3 entries in `[BackgroundTaskAttachtment]` table, with all properties set as expected, except the [UpdatedOnUtc] which not updated (it is equal to [CreatedOnUtc]

I marked the updated row (as you can see `[FilePath]` was successfully updated):
[image]
Would appreciate community insights,

Thank you

**This is the stored procedure code:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ArrangeBackgroundTaskAttachtments]
(
    @backgroundTaskId   BIGINT,
    @taskAttchs         [dbo].[BackgroundTaskAttachtmentType] READONLY
)

AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --delete all removed attachtments
    DELETE FROM [BackgroundTaskAttachtment] 
    WHERE [BackgroundTaskId] = @backgroundTaskId AND [Id] NOT IN (SELECT [Id] FROM @taskAttchs)


----Update exist key-value pairs
UPDATE [dbo].[BackgroundTaskAttachtment]
SET 
    [IsPrimary] = attachs.[IsPrimary], 
    [FilePath] = attachs.[FilePath],
    [Bytes] = attachs.[Bytes],
    [UpdatedOnUtc] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM @taskAttchs AS attachs
WHERE attachs.[Id] = [BackgroundTaskAttachtment].[Id]

--insert new records
SELECT @backgroundTaskId AS [BackgroundTaskId], [FilePath], [IsPrimary], [Bytes], GETUTCDATE() AS [CreatedOnUtc], GETUTCDATE() AS [UpdatedOnUtc]
INTO #Temp FROM @taskAttchs as atcs
WHERE atcs.[Id] NOT IN (SELECT [Id] FROM [BackgroundTaskAttachtment] AS bta WHERE bta.[BackgroundTaskId] = @backgroundTaskId )

    INSERT INTO [BackgroundTaskAttachtment]([BackgroundTaskId], [IsPrimary], [Bytes], [FilePath], [CreatedOnUtc], [UpdatedOnUtc] )
    SELECT [BackgroundTaskId], [IsPrimary], [Bytes], [FilePath], [CreatedOnUtc], [UpdatedOnUtc]
    FROM #Temp
END
```

**This is the table type (sent from CLR to SQL)**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[BackgroundTaskAttachtmentType] AS TABLE(

    [Id]                    [BIGINT]            NOT NULL,
    [FilePath]              [NVARCHAR](MAX)     NULL,
    [IsPrimary]             [BIT]               NOT NULL,
    [BackgroundTaskId]      [BIGINT]            NULL,
    [Bytes]                 [VARBINARY](MAX)    NULL
    )
GO
```

**this is the table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BackgroundTaskAttachtment]
(
    [Id]                    BIGINT          IDENTITY(1,1)           NOT NULL,
    [BackgroundTaskId]      BIGINT                                  NOT NULL,
    [IsPrimary]             BIT                                     NOT NULL        DEFAULT 0,
    [FilePath]              NVARCHAR(MAX)                           NULL,
    [Bytes]                 VARBINARY(MAX)                          NULL,
    [CreatedOnUtc]          DATETIME2                               NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedOnUtc]          DATETIME2                               NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion]            ROWVERSION                              NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BackgroundTaskAttachtment] PRIMARY KEY   CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BackgroundTaskAttachtment_BackgroundTask_Id]
        FOREIGN KEY ([BackgroundTaskId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[BackgroundTask] ([Id])
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `SYSUTCDATETIME` which returns [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx).
The `GETUTCDATE` which you are using, returns [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx).

Comment: No - it did not help - still have the same issue